# WPF - TextChangedEventArgs being fired twice, and when can e.Changes be greather than 1?

Tags: wpf

TextChangedEventArgs is being fired twice in my RichTextBox control.

Is this normal?

Also, when will e.Changes (you know the TextChangedEventArgs) be > 1. The only case I can think of is someone pasting content into it.

But other times it seems in normal typing a person can really only change 1 paragraph right?

Comment: I have the same difficulty in Windows Phone 7 development. For now I'm using a toggle function workaround, but I'll post the question with code example later today (and link to it) to see what I'm doing wrong. Stay tuned :)

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the code it's going to be very difficult to diagnose the problem.

However, having said that have you subscribed to the `TextChanged` event twice? I've had cases like this where the code to subscribe is either in the wrong place or not matched by code unsubscribing from the event.

Comment: Do I have to unsubscribe from the event as well!?

Comment: @halivingston - it depends on where you subscribe to it. If you do it once in a constructor (say) then it's not always necessary. However, if you subscribe on a button press (say) then yes you should unsubscribe.